# Is "stick your mouth to a hole" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am not sure how idiomatic it is. When someone says "stick your mouth to a hole" does he mean literally as in put your mouth in contact with the hole or close to it? I thought it was an exaggeration, but I am not sure if it is and if it is a commonly used phrase.

Here's an example of how I would use it:

> The prisoner stuck his mouth to a hole on the door in order to be fed,
>   because the guards wouldn't give them an utensil in fear that they
>   would be used as a weapon or used to dig up a hole.

Answer (score 1):

There is no idiomatic expression, it would be a literal description. *The prisoner had to be fed through an opening in the door . . . .*